# Visual Studio Emulator for Android in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

[Here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) it is mentionned that in vs 2015 it was lauched the vs android emulator which is fatest than the usual android emalutor.

How can I configure visual studio 2013 update 4 community edition to have this emulator?

Comment: Is there any possibility to make the Android emulator in vs 2013 faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging Cordova App (android) with Visual Studio 2015 New Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239195/debugging-cordova-app-android-with-visual-studio-2015-new-emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this same question myself only last week and actually posted my own answer with instructions. You can see it here..
[My question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239195/debugging-cordova-app-android-with-visual-studio-2015-new-emulator)

I am using VS 2013 professional edition though so Im not sure if there are any foibles there. If you have the 'Device' option as a target it should work..

Please mark as answer if this helps you..  Thanks, Brett

Comment: Thank you for your answer, In order to test it as I can understand I have to install first the VS 2015 in order to take the files of this emulator?

Comment: Also a user experience question. Can you run ios emulator and windows in VS 2013?

Comment: I have installed the vs 2015 in order to run the emulator but I can run it because it need Hyper-V.

Comment: Ah.. ok so you need to upgrade to a minimum of Windows Professional in order to get the HyperV.. I did that too.. Its quilte easy, you need to get a license key from Microsoft then install it through the control panel.

Comment: You could consider the Genymotion emulator as an option too? Just a thought. I didn't stay with that because I couldn't get the networking going and could get support on the free version.. but wouldn't upgrade unless I could get it working.. sort of thing.

Comment: I am .. as it happens at the moment struggling to get the loopback working so I can see the two way traffic with fiddler.. I think that might be a hyper v config issue too..  if you get there, let me know. Cheers, Brett ps.. one final thing.. You need to first run the emulator outside VS by using a command line in administrator mod pointing at the correct folder. I mention that because when I created a shortcut to a new .VHD without doing so I got a restricted access error.